# Does facebook like buttons have i18n feature?

Tags: facebook, internationalization, facebook-opengraph

in my rails app, i have a vote feature working with facebook likes.

Is their a way to have a dynamic meta facebook description (og:title) for any of the language  i support.

For instance, on my wall, i'd like that if an english person has clicked on the vote/like button it's written "i just voted for XXX" and if a french has clicked it's written "Je viens de voter pour XXX"

I have seen this documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/ but, i don't really understand how to implement it.

I was thinking that facebook used some kind of cache so it just parse the og:title once (so in one particular language) but I saw some websites with the feature...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need change js.src in standart fb js:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = '<%= fb_source_url(your_app_id) %>';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And for example add this method to application_helper.rb:

```
  def localte_to_uri
    I18n.locale.to_s.gsub('-','_')
  end

  def fb_source_url(app_id)
    "http://connect.facebook.net/#{localte_to_uri}/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=#{app_id}&version=v2.0"
  end
```

If I not mistake for france it is be like this:

```
"//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1"
```

Comment: In my case the issue was a simple typo: I just changed from `/pt-BR` to `/pt_BR` and it worked!